# Studying the Renormalizability of classically equivalent theories

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity, effective-field-theory

I am currently studying the effect that a massive, uncharged, non-minimally coupled spin $\frac{1}{2}$ field has on the background geometry upon quantization, and compare this with results in General Relativity. I will try to balance the amount of details, as there are way too many for a SE question.

Some useful notions:\

- In general, metric compatible connections on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold can be decomposed as $\Gamma=\overset{\circ}{\Gamma}+K$, Levi-Civita + Contortion, a tensor that contains linear contributions from [**Torsion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor) ${T^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}={\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}-{\Gamma^\alpha}_{\nu\mu}$, the antisymmetric part of $\Gamma$\
- the "total'' curvature tensor is ${R^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}=\overset{\circ}{R}{\vphantom{A}^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}+f(K)$\
- In General Relativity (GR), the connection is symmetric, so $T=0$ and obviously ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=\overset{\circ}{\Gamma}{\vphantom{A}^\alpha}_{\mu\nu$}$ and  ${R^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}\rightarrow\overset{\circ}{R}{\vphantom{A}^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}$\
- In Teleparallel Gravity (TEGR), torsion is allowed, but curvature vanishes ${R^\alpha}_{\beta\mu\nu}=0$. This theory has the same action of GR up to a boundary, so they are equivalent at classical level.

Premise:\

- The dynamical action for the spinor is $S=\int\bar{\Psi}\Delta\Psi$
  $$\Delta=i\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu-m+ic_1\gamma^\mu T_\mu$$
  with $T^\mu={T^{\nu\mu}}_\nu$ the torsion trace, of which I calculate the one-loop corrections (counterterms to a bare action in the $\bar{\text{MS}}$ scheme calculated with the [Heat Kernel method](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Heat_kernel_expansion_in_the_background_field_formalism))\
- The bare, background actions ready to be renormalized by the counterterms I find have many tensorial structures, so I will only show a couple. Let's say
  $$S^\text{GR}_\text{bare}=\int a_1\overset{\circ}{R}\vphantom{A}^2+a_2\overset{\circ}{R}\vphantom{A}^{\mu\nu}T_\mu T_\nu+a_3T^2(\nabla_\mu T^\mu)$$
  note how the presence of $T$ only comes from the non-minimal coupling to the spinor in the GR limit, and
  $$S^\text{TEGR}_\text{bare}=\int b_1T^4+b_2T^2(\nabla_\mu T^\mu)$$
  for which no terms in $R$ is needed, because it doesn't appear in the effective action\
- At the end of the renormalization procedure, I find that all counterterms to these actions are of the form $\delta_{a_i}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}(A+B\,a_i)$, where $A$ and $B$ are parametric functions of $c_1$ (like $A=1$, $B=2+4c_1$) so all beta functions are $\beta_{\alpha_i}=A+B\,a_i$

What I want:\

- I want to find if there are a set of values of the couplings for which the divergences of GR are equal to the divergences of "Teleparallel Gravity'', so to preserve their dynamical equivalence at quantum level.

My problem:\

- Because the Effective actions are different, what does it mean, operativetely, that the two theories are "equal''?\

My take is that the counterterms were numerically for some $c_1$, but this cannot be done term-by-term, because not all terms in the actions have the same structure, and thus comparable.

Any take?