# Conditions for two field theories to be equivalent at one-loop level

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, classical-field-theory

I am asking a much shorter, more generalized version of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762745/) in order to gather as much information as possible.

- I have two field theories $A$ and $B$ which are equal at classical level: they have the same action up to a boundary term.\
- $A$ and $B$ are both "limits'' of a broader theory, on which different constraints can be applied to obtain the desired limit.\
- In this broader theory I then calculate the one-loop effective action and the necessary counterterms to a bare, background action and the beta functions of the respective couplings.\
- In the respective limits, there are both counterterms that have the same tensorial structure, and counterterms that are exclusive to one of the two (some only in $A$, some only in $B$, some shared).

**Actual question**: what are the conditions that make $A$ and $B$ "equivalent'' at quantum level? My guess is along the lines of "they share the same divergences", and thus renormalization properties, but how does this translate operatively? Do I compare counterterms? Find ranges of couplings for which some terms have the same behavior (like sign of the beta function)?